# Did ALLAH (SWT) asked us before sending us to earth?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-basis

I heard from someone that ALLAH(SWT) created us and then took some oath and sent us on earth. I don't know how authentic it is as I do not have any reference.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You'd better support your question by using Quranic verses or authenticated hadiths.

Comment: It's asking for support/authentication for the claim. That burden is on the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

It called alast oath (عهد اَلَست).

In alame zar (عالم ذَر) which is presented of donya, God created human’s spirit which had perception and Sense. Then Allah got Confessions from human about his creator, and got oaths to worship Allah, obey his prophets and not worshiping Satan. Versus Allah oaths to help humans if they be loyal to their oaths.

This verses mention to this oath:

> "And remember the favor of Allah upon you and His covenant with which
>   He bound you when you said, "We hear and we obey"; and fear Allah .
>   Indeed, Allah is Knowing of that within the breasts."**(Surat
>   Al-Mā'idah,verse7)**
>
> "And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from
>   their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves,
>   [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have
>   testified." [This] - lest you should say on the day of Resurrection,
>   "Indeed, we were of this unaware."**(Surat Al-'A`rāf,verse172)**
>
> "And your Lord says, "Call upon Me; I will respond to you." Indeed,
>   those who disdain My worship will enter Hell [rendered]
>   contemptible."**(Surat Ghāfir,verse60)**
>
> "Did I not enjoin upon you, O children of Adam, that you not worship
>   Satan - [for] indeed, he is to you a clear enemy -And that you worship
>   [only] Me? This is a straight path."**(Surat Yā-Sīn,verse60-61)**

And Imam Ali (a.s.) said: “Allah sent prophets to remind human their oaths to Allah"

Comment: Salam brother, thanks for your answer, and the oath is now in the Hajar-al-Aswad at the wall of Ka`ba, people are encouraged to touch the oath during every single turn around the House, and no Muslims is allowed to get close to it ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is authenticated. Allah (SWT) *did* take an oath from us, when he created our souls.

Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala said in Qur'an:

> وَإِذْ أَخَذَ رَ‌بُّكَ مِن بَنِي آدَمَ مِن ظُهُورِ‌هِمْ
>   ذُرِّ‌يَّتَهُمْ وَأَشْهَدَهُمْ عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ أَلَسْتُ
>   بِرَ‌بِّكُمْ ۖ قَالُوا بَلَىٰ ۛ شَهِدْنَا ۛ أَن تَقُولُوا يَوْمَ
>   الْقِيَامَةِ إِنَّا كُنَّا عَنْ هَـٰذَا غَافِلِينَ
>
> "And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from
>   their loins - their descendants and made them **testify** of
>   themselves, [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "**Yes,
>   we have testified.**" [This] - lest you should say on the day of
>   Resurrection, "Indeed, we were of this unaware." " [Surah A'raf,
>   7:172]

Answer (score -2):

i suggest u to watch mercifulservant channel on youtube. here's the link https://youtu.be/y58jT-YgdP0 . this vid tells full stories of our souls journey supported by quran and hadist. may allah bless u always. assalamualaikum.